# Importing data from google api to my database

Tags: python, django

I need to create view which imports data from google books api and saves in my model. For now I have this view but I have no idea how to do this in Django and I don't know if this is good and what's next.

```
def book_search(self, request):
    value = ''
    apikey = ''
    params = {'q': value, 'key': apikey}
    response = request.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes', params=params)
    bookapi = response.json()
```

<<**Actualization**>>

Ok I tried to built my view but now Im getting error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

When I'm trying to run my view. I'm receiving my form but when I try to execute POST request for filled form then I'm receiving error.

views:

```
class GoogleBooks(View):
    model = Book
    form_class = SearchBookForm
    template_name = 'books/import_book.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def search(self, value):
        googleapikey = ""
        params = {"q": value, 'key': googleapikey}
        google_books = self.request.get(url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes", params=params)
        book_dict = google_books.json()
        return book_dict

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['key_word']
            bookshelf = self.search(text)
            booklist = 0
            for book in bookshelf:
                new_book = Book.objects.create(
                    title=book['items'][booklist]['volumeInfo']['title'],
                    published_date=book['items'][booklist]['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'][:3],
                    pages=book['items'][booklist]['volumeInfo']['pageCount'],
                    language=book['items'][booklist]['volumeInfo']['language'],
                )
                booklist += 1
                new_book.save()
            return redirect(reverse('books_index'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('add_book'))
```

forms:

```
class SearchBookForm(forms.Form):
    key_word = forms.CharField()
```

template:

```
{% extends "books/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="GET">
            {{ form.as_p}}
            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is what i tried to find problem but this works very well and I'm getting exactly what I want:

```
import os
import requests
import json

class gbooks():
    googleapikey=""

    def search(self, value):
        params = {"q":value, 'key':self.googleapikey}
        r = requests.get(url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes", params=params)
        rj = r.json()
        j = rj['items'][1]['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'][:4]
        return print(j)



bk = gbooks()
bk.search("Harry Potter")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I after long battle I found problem and wrote fully functional view:

```
class GoogleBooks(View):
    form_class = SearchBookForm
    template_name = 'books/import_book.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def search(self, value):
        googleapikey = ""
        params = {'q': value, 'key': googleapikey}
        google_books = requests.get(url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes", params=params)
        books_json = google_books.json()
        bookshelf = books_json['items']
        return bookshelf

    def add_book_to_library(self, bookshelf):
        for book in bookshelf:
            Book.objects.get_or_create(
                title=book['volumeInfo']['title'],
                published_date=book['volumeInfo']['publishedDate'][:4],
                pages=book['volumeInfo']['pageCount'],
                language=book['volumeInfo']['language'],
            )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            keyword = form.cleaned_data['keyword']
            books = self.search(keyword)
            self.add_book_to_library(books)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('index_books'))

        return reverse_lazy('import_books')
```

It's doing exactly what I want and problem was that I were trying to pull out from dictionary wrong values.
I tried before this:

```
google_books = self.request.get(url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes", params=params)
        book_dict = google_books.json()
        return book_dict

booklist = 0
for book in bookshelf:
    new_book = Book.objects.create(
    title=book['items'][booklist]['volumeInfo']['title'],
```

but should be like this:

```
google_books = requests.get(url="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes", params=params)
        books_json = google_books.json()
        bookshelf = books_json['items']
        return bookshelf

for book in bookshelf:
            Book.objects.get_or_create(
                title=book['volumeInfo']['title'],
```

Answer (score 2):

If you so far you're getting your api `response` without errors. You can then loop through your `bookapi` and save each object values to your `Model` as required.

To illustrate.

PS: For this illustration, I assume `bookapi` is iterable ( this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html would be helpful in case you run into any problem with working with `api` json responses )

```
        .....................
        .....................
        response = request.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes', params=params)
        bookapi = response.json()
        # loop through your data and save to model
        for i in bookapi:
            new_entry = Model(
                         field_1 = i['obj_key1'],
                         field_1 = i['obj_key1']
                         )
            new_entry.save()
```

Comment: @Kuracha from the `error` message, it looks like you've surpassed your usage quota for the day. A walk around might be creating a second API key with a new project - FYI I haven't  worked with Google's book API but I assume it's same policy with their other APIs. Let me how it goes, Thanks.

Comment: My API key was wrong because by mistake When I pasted my key I also added space on the end, after deleting space everything is ok.